# In which table the attribute set ids are stored in magento 2

Tags: database, magento2.2.2, attribute-set, configurable-product-options

In which table the attribute set ids are stored in magento 2.

I wish to save the product with its attribute set id . So Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 3):

Attribute set ids are store in `eav_attribute_set` table.

Table fields are like below

> attribute_set_id : attribute set id store.
>
> entity_type_id : entity type like customer catalog etc
>
> attribute_set_name : store attribute set name
>
> sort_order : store attribute set sort order

Answer (score 0):

Attribute Set details are present in table: `eav_attribute_set`.

Product and Attribute Set Id relation is stored in table `catalog_product_entity`.