# Assign attribute to a product using mysql Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, database, product-attribute

I am trying to assign attribute to a product in mysql, but not able to do so.
Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: please add more details .

Answer (score 0):

You want to update the attribute set for a product type:
[https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/understanding-magento-2-product-attributes-attribute-sets/#:~:text=Some%20attributes%20are%20built%20into,2%20to%20customize%20your%20products.&text=Attribute%20set%20represents%20a%20list,to%20a%20specific%20product%20family](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/understanding-magento-2-product-attributes-attribute-sets/#:%7E:text=Some%20attributes%20are%20built%20into,2%20to%20customize%20your%20products.&text=Attribute%20set%20represents%20a%20list,to%20a%20specific%20product%20family).

Check out this question/answer for where that is in the DB
[In which table the attribute set ids are stored in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225838/in-which-table-the-attribute-set-ids-are-stored-in-magento-2)